# Is it possible to insert based on a select result in MySQL?

Tags: sql, insert

i have a table called employee:

[image]

And a table department
that just has id and name

I am attempting to make an insert that would add an employee to each department that exists, in a single query, is that possible?

Comment: You can insert into table t(col1, col2...) select _col1, _col2 from bla

Comment: @SherifelKhatib but that only copies data from 1 table to another, what i want is to add him to each department, so create an insert that adds the user multiple times with different dep_id depending on how many dep_ids exist

Comment: your select statement can be a complex one such as select u.userid, d.depid from users u right join department d ...

Answer (score 1):

```
Insert Into Employees 
Select '11111', 'John', ID, 'parent'
FROM Departments
```

This will insert the same employee to each department, I hope I understand you correctly because it doesn't make sense to add the same employee to each department.

Comment: No i dont think so, department table only has 2 values, id and name for example:
1, Department1
I want to select all different departments, get their ids and make an insert for each unique id

Comment: Try the posted query it will work but don't put the ID field between quotations